# Colocar outline no USEMAP HTML5

Tags: html, css3, aplicação-web, front-end

Quero colocar borda ou outline no mapa da imagem no HTML.
Tentei usar:

```
map area{outline: 1}
```

Mas não funcionou!

Comment: coloque o seu código na pergunta, para facilitar a visualização do problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Segunda o W3C:**

> The `area` element represents either a hyperlink with some text and a corresponding area on an `image map`, or a dead area on an `image map`.

Traduzindo *"O elemento de `area` representa um hiperlink com algum texto e uma área correspondente em um `image map` ou uma área morta em um `image map`"*

***Fonte:*** https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/area.html

Isso significa que a `area` é representada dentro do `map` através das coordenadas. Teoricamente essa área não é renderizada visualmente, ela é um *hiperlink* referenciado dentro do um `map` que por sua vez é "indexado" como um mapa de áreas ativas sobre uma imagem.

Veja que vc pode trocar a cor da *pseudo-class* `:link`, porém isso muito provavelmente é por uma questão de acessibilidade do user-agent. Veja como esse elemento é renderizado pelo Browser:

```
map area:link {
  outline: red auto 5px !important;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas repare que por default a `area` tem `display:none`

https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/area.html#area-display

---

## Soluções para o seu caso

Usar algum plugin tipo o **Mapper.js**

http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/

Ou então vc pode construir um mapa responsivo sobre uma imagem como nesse exemplo

Execute o Snippet abaixo, e depois clica em ***"Página toda"*** vc vai ver o @media funcionando, o `.container` com a imagem vai aumentar, mas não vai perder a referencia do mapa.

Aqui tem uma ferramente para te ajudar a encontrar as porcentagens para posicionar os links sob a imagem. https://www.zaneray.com/responsive-image-map/

**OBS:** Dentro do Snippet links não funcionam, mas quando vc copiar para a sua página vai funcionar normal.

*(Essa técnica não se aplica caso vc use a largura do `.container` em %, ai não da certo)*

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/400/400);
    background-position:center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.container a {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
.container a + a {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .5);
    transform: rotate(-12deg);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="https://www.google.com.br/" target="_black" title="Link 1" style="position: absolute; left: 42.25%; top: 26.25%; width: 10.25%; height: 7.25%; z-index: 2;"></a>
    <a href="https://www.globo.com/" target="_black" title="Link 2" style="position: absolute; left: 59%; top: 23.5%; width: 10.5%; height: 6.75%; z-index: 2;"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, nota 10 !

Comment: Valeu @LuisFelipe tmj

Comment: @hugocsl dessa maneira feita, caso eu queira que apareça o ".container a" apenas ao passar ao mouse, qual seria a melhor maneira?

Comment: @JVEUZEBIO primeiro coloca `.container a {opacity:0}` e depois `.container a:hover {opacity:1}` isso deve resolver

Comment: @hugocsl valeu!